# Question from Lee's proof that closed Lie subgroup is embedded. (Computation of differential of the group multiplication map)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I am reading the following proof from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.
Below is part of the proof on showing that $H$ is embedded if $H$ is a closed Lie subgroup. In the below proof, why does the differential of $\psi$ at $(e,e)$ satisfy $d \psi(X,0)=X$ and $d\psi(0,Y)=Y$ for $X \in T_e V$ , $Y \in T_eS$, and how does this show that $d\psi_{(e,e)}$ is bijective? I cannot understand this line of the proof. I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had the same question  [answered nicely here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3287364/differential-of-multiplication-map-of-lie-group)

Comment: First note that $T_{(e,e)}(V\times S) \cong T_eV \oplus T_eS = T_eG$. If you can figure out that $d\psi(0,Y)=Y$ and $d\psi(X,0)=X$ (by comment above or Ivo’s answer below) then easy to see that $d\psi_{(e,e)}$ is bijective.

Comment: @Sou How is it easy to see? I’m actually confused why these two equations lead to bijectivity.

Comment: Use definition of bijectivity and $(X,Y)=(X,0)+(Y,0)$ and linearity of $d\psi$. Alternatively show that $\text{Ker}d\psi = \{(0,0)\}$

Comment: @Sou okay so we need to use the fact that $T_e G$ is a direct sum decomposition?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\psi$ is the multiplication, to compute ${\rm d}\psi_{(e,e)}(X,0)$, one may take the curve $\alpha(t) = (\alpha_1(t),e)$, where $\alpha_1(0) = e$ and $\alpha_1'(0)=X$. This way: $${\rm d}\psi_{(e,e)}(X,0)= \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|_{t=0} \psi(\alpha(t)) = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|_{t=0} \alpha_1(t)e = \alpha_1'(0) =X.$$Similarly we have ${\rm d}\psi_{(e,e)}(0,Y) = Y$. It is like computing partial derivatives of functions depending on two variables in Calculus 2. Since you're taking the second entry of $(X,0)$ to be zero and this is based at the point $(e,e)$, it amouns to computing the derivative at the point $e$ evaluated at $X$ of the map $x\mapsto \psi(x,e) = x$, which is the identity.

Comment: In the comparison to computing partial derivatives, do you mean because the second entry is $0$, we can ignore the second component and consider it as computing the derivative as a function of only the first component with the second component fixed at the base point $e$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$