# A question on Lie Groups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $G$ be a Lie group.
(a) Let $m : G \times G \to G$ denote the multiplication map. Using Proposition
3.14 of john lee smooth manifolds (The Tangent Space to a Product Manifold) to identify $T_{(e,e)}(G \times G)$ with $T_e(G) \bigoplus T_e(G)$, Show that:

(a) the differential $dm_(e,e)(X,Y)=X + Y$

(b) Let $i: G \to G$ denote the invertion map. show that $di_e: T_eG \to T_eG$ is given by $di_e(X)= -X$

This is problem 7-2 of John Lee Smooth Manifolds.

I already solved this wanna see if my solution is correct or not. thanks.

Here is my solution:

We have :

$dm_{(e,e)}(X,Y) = dm_{(e,e)}(X,0)+dm_{(e,e)}(0,Y)=d(m^{1})_e(X)+d(m^{2})_e(Y)$

Which $m^1:G \to G $ is defined by $x \mapsto m(x,e)$ , $m^2:G \to G $ defined by $y \mapsto m(e,y)$, but $m^1 = m^2 = Id_G$ ,so $dm_{(e,e)}(X,Y)=X+Y$ this proves (a). Put $ n= m \circ p \circ s$ which $s :G \to G \times G$ is defined by $x \mapsto (x,x)$ and $p:G \times G \to G \times G$ is defined by $(x,y) \mapsto (x,i(y))$ then $n$ is a constant map ,so:
\begin{align}
0 = dn_e(X)=dm_{(e,e)}(dp_{(e,e)}(ds_e(X)))=dm_{(e,e)}(dp_{(e,e)}(X,X))&=dm_{(e,e)}(X,di_e(X))\\&=X+di_e(X)
\end{align}

so $di_e(X)=-X$

Comment: It looks correct to me. Nice proof!

Comment: Related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3287364/differential-of-multiplication-map-of-lie-group/3287594#3287594

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your proof is very neat! It works :)

Maybe you could argue a bit better why $dm_{(e, e)} (x, 0) = (d m_1) _e(X) $, which follows in your compositional style by writing $m(x, e) = m \circ i_1$. Here $i_1 : G \to G \times G$ is defined by $i_1(x) = (x, e) $.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a kinda awkward way to solve the problem. For (a),  we know that we have isomorphism $\alpha : T_{(e,e)(G \times G)} \to T_eG \oplus T_eG$ given by
$$
\alpha(v) = \Big(d(\pi_1)_{(e,e)}(v), d(\pi_2)_{(e,e)}(v) \Big),
$$
with $\pi_1, \pi_2 : G \times G \to G$ is a canonical projection $\pi(g,h) = g, \,\pi_2(g,h) = h$. Let $\mathtt{i}, \mathtt{j} : G \hookrightarrow G \times G$ is embedding $\mathtt{i}(g)=(g,e), \, \mathtt{j}(g)=(e,g)$. Then inverse of $\alpha$ is $\beta : T_eG \oplus T_eG \to T_{(e,e)}(G \times G)$ given by
$$
\beta(X,Y) = d\mathtt{i}_e(X) + d\mathtt{j}_e(Y).
$$
Notation $dm_{(e,e)}$ given in the problem is composition of $dm_{(e,e)} : T_{(e,e)}(G \times G) \to T_eG$ with isomorphism $\beta$. Denote $\gamma  := dm_{(e,e)} \circ \beta $.
$$
\gamma : T_eG \oplus T_eG \xrightarrow{\beta}T_{(e,e)}(G\times G) \xrightarrow{dm_{(e,e)}} T_eG.
$$
With this noatation, we need to show that $\gamma(X,Y) = X + Y$. We know that  $m \circ \mathtt{i} = \text{Id}_G$ and $m \circ \mathtt{j} = \text{Id}_G$, so
\begin{align*}
\gamma(X,Y) &= dm_{(e,e)} \circ \beta(X,Y) \\
&= dm_{(e,e)} (d\mathtt{i}_e(X)+d\mathtt{j}_e(Y)) \\ &= dm_{(e,e)} (d\mathtt{i}_e(X)) + dm_{(e,e)} (d\mathtt{j}_e(Y)) \\
&= d(m \circ \mathtt{i})_e(X) + d(m \circ \mathtt{j})_e(Y) \\
&= X + Y.
\end{align*}
For (b), we use result from (a). We have trivial map $E : g \mapsto e \in G$. So we can decompose $E$ as $g \mapsto (g,g^{-1}) \mapsto gg^{-1}$. Define $\mathtt{I}(g) := (g,g^{-1})$. Hence
$$
E : G  \xrightarrow{\mathtt{I}} G \times G \xrightarrow{m} G.
$$
It's clear that $\pi_1 \circ \mathtt{I} = \text{Id}_G$ dan $\pi_2 \circ \mathtt{I} = i$. Because diffrential of $E$ is zero map and differential of $m$ is known, then we can find differential of
$i$. By the following commutattive diagram

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

we have for any $X \in TeG$,
\begin{align*}
    dE_e(X) &= ( dm_{(e,e)} \circ d\mathtt{I}_e ) (X)  \\
    &= (dm_{(e,e)} \circ \text{Id} \circ d\mathtt{I} )(X) \\ 
    &= (dm_{(e,e)} \circ \beta \circ \alpha \circ d\mathtt{I} )(X) \\
    &= (dm_{(e,e)} \circ \beta ) \circ (\alpha \circ d\mathtt{I}_e) (X) \\
    &= \gamma \circ \big( \alpha \circ d\mathtt{I}_e(X) \big) \\
    &= \gamma \big( d\pi_1 \circ d\mathtt{I}_e (X), d\pi_2 \circ d\mathtt{I}_e (X) \big) \\
    &= \gamma \big( d\text{Id}_G(X), di_e(X) \big) \\
    &=  d\text{Id}_G(X) + di_e(X) \\
    &=  X + di_e(X).
\end{align*}
So since $dE_e=0$ then $di_e(X) = -X$.